# Counterexample for "Filtration of stopping time equals filtration generated by stopped process"

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, filtrations

I am working in a discrete setting. Consider any stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with its natural filtration $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and a stopping time $\tau$. We know that
$$\mathcal F_\tau = \sigma(\tau,X_n^\tau, n\in\mathbb N).$$
For example in [Filtration of stopping time equal to the natural filtration of the stopped process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618328/filtration-of-stopping-time-equal-to-the-natural-filtration-of-the-stopped-proce) it is discussed if
$$\mathcal F_\tau = \sigma(X_t^\tau, t\in\mathbb R_+)$$
holds in the continuous case. I am interested in the discrete analogon
$$\mathcal F_\tau = \sigma(X_n^\tau, n\in\mathbb N).\tag{$\ast$}\label{1}$$

Shiryaev shows in his book "Optimal Stopping Rules" Stochastic Modelling and Applied Probability 8 in Springer 2008 that in the continuous case, the result is true if the probability space $\Omega$ is sufficiently rich, that means for all $t\ge0$ and $\omega\in\Omega$ there exists $\omega'\in\Omega$ such that $X_s(\omega')=X_{s\wedge t}(\omega)$ for all $s\ge0$ holds. The proof suggests that the analogue statement also holds in discrete time case.

I am looking for a counterexample, in which \eqref{1} does not hold. I tried to look at probability spaces consisting of only a few points but could not find any counterexample. For any suggestions, I am very thankful.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2319889/36150)